# ERROR DOMException: Element.closest: '*:has(> .form-control)' is not a valid selector

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I got this error after adding the `formControlName` directive to the input:

```
<input class='w-100' id='card-number' type='text' formControlName='cardNumber'/>
```

If i remove `formControlName` it will be fixed. I don't have any .form-control class in my css and js files.

What can i do to resolve that?

Comment: Are you using `angularjs` or `angular`? There's different tages for each (refer to the tag descriptions). In case it's angular, it'd be helpful if you could add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You could use [Stacblitz](https://www.stackblitz.com) to quickly create one!

Comment: Why angular version are you using ?

Comment: @Cuzy it's angular 14 and I can't reproduce that error again.